# Browser: Randomly Opens Pages in New Windows Without Reason?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, firefox, browser, browser-tabs

This is a very strange thing I've noticed on my computer and past computers over this past year or more. I know when page are meant to open in a new Window and know which settings to use on my browser for this. But on both my browsers Chrome and Firefox, I have this really strange issue. I'm starting to think it's a hacker.

When I right click links and select **Open Link in New Tab**, sometimes they will randomly open in a new window and today it is happening a lot. Like lots and lots. I'm getting really creeped out by it and YES I understand when a link opens in a new window and when it isn't supposed to. And none of these links are meant to open in a new Window.

Let me give you an example:

1. I searched Google about my issue and clicked on the result that I thought good.
   It opened in a new tab but half way through loading in new tab it opens into a new window.
2. Recently, I decided to record my screen and while recording my screen using Camtasia, the issue stops. When I stop recording it starts again, as if it's a human operated issue. VERY strange.

This has been going on for months on my old and new computer and on both Firefox and Chrome. Is there something I can do to fix this intermittent problem?

Answer (score 3):

Luckily, I highly doubt a hacker is in your computer just to intermittently open up links you clicked on in a new window instead of new tabs or the same window. :)

It sounds to me like your <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is intermittently sticking.

When you got your new computer, did you keep your previous mouse and keyboard?  Are they wired or wireless?  Have they been cleaned in the last few years?

Try and new/different keyboard and/or mouse.